# Connection refused on C# unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

When I do a simple unit testing in C#, 
it's throwing  "System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it **127.0.0.1:52747**"

Unit test Cs file:

[image]

CS file for the get method:

[image]

When I run test method , it's keep on refusing

Comment: Does this url work for you from browser?

Comment: Hitting a http endpoint is _odd_ in a unit test. Not illegal, per se. But odd...

Comment: Unit Testing the client side code usually should be without an active connection to Server. Seems your Server (on Localhost:52747) is not Running.

Comment: How are you hosting the api you intend to call? (I suspect I know the answer to this, but asking with the intent of clarifying the question...)

Comment: @alex: Actullay it's greatly with browser!!!!

Comment: is there any solution for this?

Comment: In a unit test you probably don't want to be invoking external resources. Instead of using HttpClient you could call a method on an interface.I.e. Inject IHttpClient.

Comment: In my case I get that error from everywhere (browser, external client)  when server is hosted as a part of Unit test

Comment: This is quite old but I will add here my little experience.
I often have a problem with executing https request in MsTests. xunit in console works properly.
I don't know if its the same issue for you since its HTTP and my bet is that connection gets refused because of tls version but you can give it a try :)